# Converting ModelBuilder Value to a String in Python to use in Calculate Field Expression

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am trying to take a Value from a ModelBuilder Feature Selection Iterator and pass it to the Calculate Field Python Expression in order to write values to the field of a feature selection in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.0.

[image: My Model]

My model iterates over the Features in Gridline_Grid by PageName, Value becomes the PageName Value. Then that Selected Feature is used to Select By Location all the NRN_Anno features intersecting it. Then the Selection has it's field GRIDS calculated using a Python expression that is designed to look at GRIDS and if it is 0 recalculate it to %Value% (the value from the iterator) if it is not 0 pass the current GRID value to a concatenate expression with %Value% and recalculate the field to a concatenation of both values.

```
def reclass(GRIDS):
if (GRIDS == '0'):
    return str(%Value%)
else:
    return (GRIDS)+', '+ str(%Value%)
```

The model keeps telling me the Value sotred in %Value% is not defined. This is telling me that python is returning the value from the parameter %Value% but I cannot seem to get it to read it as a string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently '%Value%' works... not sure why.

```
def reclass(GRIDS):
    if (GRIDS == '0'):
        return '%Value%'
    else:
        return (GRIDS)+', '+ '%Value%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to your answer, the note in the [Inline variable substitution](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/inline-variable-substitution.htm)
states:

> "You must enclose inline variables that are strings within quotation
> marks ('%string variable%') in an expression. Inline variables that
> are numbers do not require quotation marks."

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I didn't see that anywhere I honestly just started throwing crap at the wall to see what stuck when I found the answer. It seems to me esri made that less intuitive than what it needed to be...